# Real time synchronization for directory in Linux

Tags: linux, synchronization

I have two linux web servers (X and Y) serving my website by load-balancer, the user can upload his file (image for example) via web form, this file will go to

```
/var/www/files/token/filename.ext
```

**NOW THE QUESTION IS:**
How Could I keep **files** directory synchronized in real time manner between the two servers (given that **files** directory contains sub and sub-sub directories in it. I don't want to use NFS (for the purpose of high availability)
Any scenario is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux kernel has a feature called "inotify" which detects inode changes, in this case, it can be used to detect change in directory content. But I am not sure if there is any CLI tool for it.

Once change is detected, we can use common file synchronization tools such as rsync to synchronize new/changed files to other servers.

This idea is more like "pushing", which is more responsive than polling at regular interval.

Comment: INotify is one level-depth in directory, and my directory has sub and sub-sub dirs :) i thought about it already, but it wouldn't work with sub-dirs.

Comment: @Alaa Linux kernel has a feature called "inotify" which detects inode changes, in this case, it can be used to detect change in directory content. :)

Comment: @Alaa inotify is probably the only choice when it comes to monitoring FS changes. Although it is not capable of monitoring directory content recursively, but it can be worked around by monitoring file/dir creation in parent directory, and adding new watchers when subdirs are created. BTW, this may help: http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

Comment: Thanks a million Howard, could you please give me a hint of how to create a watcher automatically when subdir is created? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Alaa No problem. A real example will be in the source code of `inotifywait`, its manual claims: "Newly created subdirectories will also be watched".